# Collection FindById() not working . Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my node js code for specific route.
`

```
        DiscountCoupon.findById(req.body._id,function (err, data) {

            data.coupon_code = req.body.coupon_code;
            data.status = req.body.status;
            data.max_redemption = req.body.max_redemption;
            data.expiry_date = req.body.expiry_date;
            data.valid_from = req.body.valid_from;

            data.discount_value = req.body.discount_value;
            data.is_percentage = req.body.is_percentage;
            data.max_discount_amount = req.body.max_discount_amount;
            data.save(function (err, regDoc) {
                if (err)
                    return next(err);
                if (!regDoc)
                    return next(new Error('not found'));

                return res.status(200).send({ 'message': 'Record updated.' });
            });
        });
```

`

```
{   "max_discount_amount": 50,
    "is_percentage": false,
    "discount_value": 50,
    "valid_from": "2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "expiry_date": "2017-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "max_redemption": 100,
    "coupon_code": "CODE50",
    "_id": "5a12eb396b6fc23f7c2c63cc",
    "created_date": "2017-11-20T14:48:08.559Z",
    "status": true }
```

i'm not getting any error message or any result.
Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: You are not checking for the errors that findById can give you. You also have two parameter variables called `err`.

Comment: You are not getting errors because you are not checking errors in your findById

Comment: Can you guys be more specific?

Comment: See Lenin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below

```
DiscountCoupon.findById(req.body._id,function (err, data) {
            if(err)
               return next(err);

            data.coupon_code = req.body.coupon_code;
            data.status = req.body.status;
            data.max_redemption = req.body.max_redemption;
            data.expiry_date = req.body.expiry_date;
            data.valid_from = req.body.valid_from;

            data.discount_value = req.body.discount_value;
            data.is_percentage = req.body.is_percentage;
            data.max_discount_amount = req.body.max_discount_amount;
            data.save(function (err1, regDoc) {
                if (err1)
                    return next(err1);
                if (!regDoc)
                    return next(new Error('not found'));

                return res.status(200).send({ 'message': 'Record updated.' });
            });
        });
```